# How do I get museum items / collections?

Tags: puzzle-craft

I've been playing Puzzle Craft for four months now and am close to completing the app (or maxing the levels, at least). However, I have not yet found a single 'collection' (the items shown in the museum). How might I find these?

Answer (score 0):

You can only find the collectible items in chests. There is a building to upgrade the chest appearing, which will improve the chest to mythic when maxed.

The type of chest only determine the type of collection items you can found. When you have mythic chests its only matter of luck.

You can build/upgrade your chapel in order to improve your chances of finding collection in chests.